# Constructor Injection to access service

Tags: inversion-of-control, factory-pattern, mvvmcross

Is there a better way to consume a service in mvvmcross by constructor injection?
For example, I have my object in a plugin implementation

```
public class MyObject : IMyObject
{
   public MyObject (int id) 
   {
      _id = id;
   }
}
```

and want to consume it somewhere the portable core (in the buisness layer) like this :

```
public void ConsumeTheService()
{
    int i = 50;
    var myObject = this.GetService<IMyObject>(i);
}
```

Actually, I only use a setter to get my id back in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your update... if you are asking about how to get:

```
    var myObject = this.GetService<IMyObject>(50);
```

and for this to return an object which is initiaised as `new MyObject(50)`

then I would instead recommend that you implement an interface

```
public interface IMyObjectFactory
{
    IMyObject CreateMyObject(int i);
}
```

with an implementation:

```
public class MyObjectFactory : IMyObjectFactory
{
    public IMyObject CreateMyObject(int i)
    {
        return new MyObject(i);
    }
}
```

you can then register this `IMyObjectFactory` with IoC

Comment: Exactly, that's a way I tought of. But may be it'll be practical to construct the retreived service with parameter injection in the constructor. I think this is how you did for the viewmodel construction as well.

Comment: Yes, you can of course write anything you want to :) And there's open source code in Mvx you can use Ms-PL :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your example - not sure what `intValue` does in `GetService`

Regardless:

- MvvmCross v3 includes constructor injection - see some details on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html
- Others have also implemented constructor injection within vNext - e.g. https://github.com/gshackles/CrossBar/ and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/a-second-take-on-constructor-injection.html
- The IoC within MvvmCross is completely replaceable - so you can use other IoC mechanisms if you want to (but this does require some code from you)

Comment: Sorry for not be clearer than that (I updated my post). In vnext which I a m using, there is constructor injection (string only for now I think) when using navigaterequest in mvx modelview. What I want is constructor injection in a service consumer, as I am using this for a plugin.